# Extract array with different size from file

Tags: python, arrays, database, csv, extract

I have to extract tables from file (.csv or .txt), let's assume file is csv
There are different tables in this file with different size (500x5 , 200x3,...)
I need to extract them in different array in order to load them in a database

Structure of my file :

```
Book of sales du 01/01/2014 au 31/12/2050;;;;;;;;;;;

Sales;;;;;;;;;;;

Date;Invoice;Client;Txt;Price

19/02/2015;1;Johnny;coloris: 002, taille: 54/18;82,03€

21/02/2015;2;Florian;coloris: 005PL, taille: 56/17;78,34€
Total;;;;10 700,74€

;;;;;;;;;;;

Avoirs générés;;;;;;;;;;;

Date;N° Avoir;Client

04/03/2015;1;Johnny

28/03/2015;2;Jacques-Elie

Total;;698,45€
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

To process this data you will need to write a simple parser.

A parser is a small state machine.  Depending on the current state and the input that it sees next, it moves to some new state.  As it moves between the states it gathers the inputs and create some sort of tree structure.  You can try to visualize this by drawing circles for each state and lines connecting them as I describe the states your parser needs to go through.  Label each line with the input you need in order to move between the states.

Your data starts in the initial state (awaiting header), expecting a header line with a date range:

```
Book of sales du 01/01/2014 au 31/12/2050;;;;;;;;;;;
```

You need to read the line, check that it matches the expected format, extract and keep the date range, then move to the next state (awaiting table).

Your tables seem to start with a name followed by 11 semicolons.  For example:

```
Sales;;;;;;;;;;;
```

If you detect a line ending with 11 semicolons then you need to start a new table with the given table name and move to state (expecting field names).

Field names are strings separated by semicolons:

```
Date;Invoice;Client;Txt;Price
```

You need to split the header line on semicolon, save the field names and move to the new state (processing data).

Your data is practically the same as the header, being field values separated by semicolons:

```
19/02/2015;1;Johnny;coloris: 002, taille: 54/18;82,03€
```

Again, you read, split and save.  This time you stay in the current state (processing data) since you may have more than one record in the table.

The summary row for the table has the same fields, with Total instead of Date in this case:

```
Total;;;;10 700,74€
```

So if you see a line starting with "Total" while in (processing data), you transition into the state (summary) and save the totals.

From (summary), you transition to (end table), which is a line of semicolons:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Or maybe this is an empty table, and not every table ends with semicolons.  I can't tell since your sample dataset only has two tables, the last one at the end of the file.

After processing (end table), you transition back to (awaiting table), ready for the next table.  If instead you see the end of file, then you transition to (final state) and you are done parsing.

Since header, data and summary rows are all basically the same structure, we can collapse them into a single state (processing data), and after we are done processing, we can handle the first and last lines of the table specially since they are then easy to find.  This keeps are parser simpler and so easier to debug.

Similarly, if we introduce the notion of an empty table, we can simplify our parser further since we don't need an (end table) state.  We just treat it as the start of an empty table with no headers, data or summary.  Easy enough to ignore empty tables when we are done parsing.  Furthermore, we can pretend that the first table starts after an empty table, so we can start in the (processing data) state and have everything work out fine.

The blank lines between each row in your input (probably carriage-return+linefeed from windows) can be stripped out.

Putting it together, the parser becomes:

```
with open file:
    # transition to (awaiting header)
    read header
    # transition to (processing data)
    current table = empty
    for each line:
        # strip blank
        if blank: # blank does not change state
            continue
        if new table line:  
            # transition to (new table)
            save current table if any
            make new table and set it to current table
            # transition to (processing data)
        else:
            # transition to (processing data)
            split line into data columns
            # stay in (processing data)
    save current table if any
    # transition to (final state)
```

Making this a bit more pythonic:

```
tables = []
with open(filename) as file:
    line = file.readline()
    start_date, end_date = line[17:27], line[31:41]
    table_name, table_rows = "", [] # pretend we start with a blank table
    for line in file:              # reads lines one at a time until the end
        line = line.strip()        # remove linefeed from end of line
        if not line:               # check for blank line
            continue
        if line.endswith(';'*11):  # line ends with 11 semicolons
            # save the existing table; the first table will be blank
            tables.append((table_name, table_rows))
            table_name = line[:-11]  # name is all but the last 11 semicolons
            table_rows = []
        else:
            fields = line.split(';')
            table_rows.append(fields)
    # save the current table
    table.append((table_name, table_rows))
```

You should now have a list of tables (some of them may be empty).

```
# maybe record start_date, end_date
# process each table
for table_name, table_rows in tables:
    if not table_rows: # table is blank
        continue

    fields = table_rows[0]
    if table_rows[-1][0] == "Total":
        rows = table_rows[1:-1]
        summary = table_rows[-1]
    else:
        rows = table_rows[1:]
        summary = None
    save_table(table_name, fields, rows, summary)
```

This parser started out simple, and we took some shortcuts to make it even simpler.

If the language was a little more complicated, we would have left it in the more abstract form:

```
state = 0
for line in file:
    if state == 0:
        if line matches transition from 0 to 0:
            state = 0
            save line data for state 0
        elif line matches transition from 0 to 1:
            state = 1
            save line data for state 1
        elif line matches transition from 0 to 2:
            ...
    elif state == 1: 
        if line matches transition from 1 to 0:
            state = 0
            save line data for state 0
        elif line matches transition from 1 to 1:
            state = 1
            save line data for state 1
        elif line matches transition from 1 to 2:
            ...
    elif state == 2:
        ...
```

The ideas in this post will cover much of the data you need to process.

For more complicated data formats with deeply nested structures where you have to match a start structure with an end structure you need to use a real parser, such as provided by pyparsing.  Even simple math expressions with parenthesis are hard to do without parser tools.

Comment: Hi Neapolitan,Thak you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply

I wrote this :
`
    lines=[]
    with open (path+"CaParArticle.csv") as tt:
        content = [line.strip() for line in tt.readlines()]

```
import re
re.findall("Date..",content[3])

idx_date=[i for i, item in enumerate(content) if re.search('Date', item)]
idx_total=[i for i, item in enumerate(content) if re.search('Total [^H^T]|TOTAL [^H^T]', item)]
tab={}
tit={}
for i in range( len(idx_date) ):
tab[i]=pd.DataFrame( [ sub.split(";") for sub in content[idx_date[i]+1:idx_total[i]] ], \
        columns=content[idx_date[i]].split(";")  )
    tit[i]=content[idx_total[i]][6: content[idx_total[i]].index(";")-1  ]\
        .replace('des ','').upper().replace(' ','_')

tab={ tit[key]: value for key,value in tab.items()  }
```

`

Comment: You will run into problems if a field happens to contain 'Date' (e.g., if the Client is 'Make A Date' dating service).  Splitting on the table separator seems like a much safer bet.

Comment: `for date_i, total_i in zip(idx_date, idx_total)` will make your code a little cleaner.  You don't need `i` since you can assign `title` as you have assigned `tit[i]`, and then assign `tab[title]` as you have assigned `tab[i]`; this also removes the dictionary reshuffling after the loop.